# Compilation error ActiViz with VTK 7, GCC XML, C++ on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, compilation, vtk

I'm trying to compile ActiViz with VTK 7 on Windows 8.1 using Visual studio 2008 and I'm still getting compilation error `'value' is not a member of std::tr1::is_enum<vtkContourRepresentationPoint*>'` in source code of GCC XML, which ActiViz uses. But when I compile GCC XML alone there is no error.
Can anybody please help me with this issue? I trying to resolve this error whole day and I'm not able to find any solution.
Thanks.

Here is complete output from compiler:

```
VTK7/VTK-7.0.0/Interaction/Widgets/vtkContourRepresentation.h:104:   instantiated from here

16>  gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/Vc10/Include/type_traits:611: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::tr1::is_enum<vtkContourRepresentationPoint*>'

16>  gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/Vc10/Include/xutility: In instantiation of 'std::_Ptr_cat_helper<vtkContourRepresentationPoint*, vtkContourRepresentationPoint*>':

16>  gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/Vc10/Include/xutility:2535:   instantiated from '_OutIt std::_Move(_InIt, _InIt, _OutIt) [with _InIt = vtkContourRepresentationPoint**, _OutIt = vtkContourRepresentationPoint**]'

16>  gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/Vc10/Include/vector:1207:   instantiated from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<_Ty, _Ax> > std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<_Ty, _Ax> >, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<_Ty, _Ax> >) [with _Ty = vtkContourRepresentationPoint*, _Ax = std::allocator<vtkContourRepresentationPoint*>]'

16>  gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/Vc10/Include/vector:1218:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>::clear() [with _Ty = vtkContourRepresentationPoint*, _Ax = std::allocator<vtkContourRepresentationPoint*>]'
```

Comment: ActiViz doesn't support VTK 7.0 and probably never will. I believe VTK 6.2 is the newest version supported.